# Gradle project Sync failed in android studio 3.2

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I cant build my project because of this error

ERROR: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.jgabrielfreitas:BlurImageView:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update all Play Services and Firebase libraries to their latest version.

You can find the latest version of each library here https://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: Yes you should do it manually unfortunately, there is no automatic update. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: what does it mean  -                                                                                              ERROR: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Comment: You need to set all firebase and google play services to the same verison. Set them to  16.0.1 in your case and try to sync.

Comment: this helped me to solve the problem very easily https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the play-services from

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0' to 
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.1'
```

and try to add the below repos in project build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```